# Undefined variable in Javascript: difference between typeof and not exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined

I don't understand the difference between these two ways of checking if a variable is undefined:

```
if (typeof res.locals.user.hashnodes === 'undefined') {
        morphemes = 0;
}
```

and

```
if (!res.locals.user.hashnodes) {
       morphemes = 0;
}
```

For me, only the second option works, the first one doesn't. Anyone knows why?

(res.locals.user are the user settings I pass in my Node Js app).

Thank you!

Comment: Most likely because `res.locals.user.hashnodes` is not `undefined`, but a different kind of falsy value (e. g. `null`, `false` or `0`).

Comment: would ! work on an undefined one? or I need to make two checks then if I want to cover all the possibilities?

Comment: Are you getting a JavaScript error and if so what is it? Or is the logic not functioning as you expect?

Comment: @deemeetree Yes, it would, since `undefined` is a falsy value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (!res.locals.user.hashnodes)` will also check for existing yet false values.
`0, false, '', null, 'undefined', []` will all evaluate to `true` if you only use `!`.

([Here's a more thorough list of what evaluates to what](http://zero.milosz.ca/))

So what value does your local hold?

```
console.log(typeof res.locals.user.hashnodes)
```

If it's anything else than `'undefined'`, there's your answer

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has the so-called falsey variables, this means that `!res.locals.user.hashnodes` evaluates to `undefined`, `0`, `false` and a few more. Here's some more info on falsey and truthy variables.

http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Answer (score 1):

The second will set `morphemes = 0` if `res.locals.user.hashnodes` is `undefined` ***or*** `false` ***or*** `null` ***or*** `0`

where as the fist will only do so it it is `undefined`